# I want to install a magento in a subfolder (NOT sub-domain) of my domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.9

Basically, I own a domain that is hosted somewhere... My current domain works just fine, so when I access www.mydomain.com, my website shows up.

Now, what I want to do is install a magento in a folder, so that I can access it and work with it like: www.mydomain.com/mymagento (for the frontend) and www.mydomain.com/mymagento/admin (for the backend)

What I did so far is I downloaded the latest version of magento (1.9.2.1) and created a folder in my domain, called mymagento.
I copied the tar.gz archive in mymagento folder, then I went (also with ssh) in the folder, and ran the recommended permission commands like bellow:

```
chmod -R o+w app/etc/
chmod -R o+w var/
chmod -R o+w media/
```

Now I expect to be able to reach my magento installation, but something tells me I should run the web installer... well, I can't. Because I get an empty page whenever I try.

I should probably mention that I used to have an earlier version of magento in the same folder(I think it was a version 1.7), and I could access it back then. I moved the contents of that folder in a temp folder and did the unpacking of the latest tar.gz file (1.9.2.1) in the same place. When I look at the folder structure, it looks fine, just like the previous magento, but whne I try to run it, in the browser, I get nothing. I tried acceesing things like

```
www.mydomain.com/mymagento
www.mydomain.com/mymagento/index.php
www.mydomain.com/mymagento/install.php
```

but nothing changed... I still get an empty page.

My purpose for this is to have an online e-shop that I can play with (and configure), do my customisations, and when it's done, just move it somewhere, in a new domain's root folder and start playing....

SO, what steps do I have to make to properly install an instance of magento in my "mymagento" folder?

Is this a .htaccess problem?

Comment: If that's your goal, what's wrong running a VM that mirrors your deployment environment, play with it locally, use git to track the changed files and all you're left with is `git clone <your repo>` - voila, job done. It's just a suggestion, however judging by Magento's docs - it appears it wants the whole domain for itself. I don't know if you'll get around it, but I wish you all the luck and I'm sorry I couldn't provide solution you wanted (but that's why alternatives are good too).

Comment: So I can install a magento on my windows to play with it. But I already did that. So the localhost (windows machine) is my testing project, then there is the remote server where I want to deploy only the tested stuff, so just what works on my localmachine. At the end I will have a perfectly working shop on the remote host, ready to deploy to the final destination. I do not use git in general, especially since I am the only developer working on the project, and also, in order to use git I would need first, a working environment, a working project. That is what I am after...

Comment: Ryan , you missunderstood my problem. I cannot seem to be able to run the web install of magento, when it is unpacked in a subfolder. That is what is going on. When installing it in the www root, the installer runs just fine, but when I place the unpacked files in a sub-folder, I cannot seem to be able to run the installer or anything related with magento, for that matter

Answer (score 0):

I think  you have  to make changes in your .htaccess file of www.mydomain.com  so that  you can access www.mydomain.com/mymagento .right now  your domain .htaccess file is stopping you from accessing your magento folder .

Comment: Could you please tell me what should my htaccess file contain?

Comment: Please follow this link  http://blog.husseycoding.co.uk/2013/01/installing-magento-in-subdirectory.html